# Using VS2010 Image Library when image contains more than one icon

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'd like to create a button containing an image (remove) from the [VS2010 Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247035%28VS.100%29.aspx) in WPF (...\_Common Elements\Actions\remove.png). This image actually contains four versions of the icon in different sizes. How do I go about using the first one of these?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the files in the `_Common Elements` are meant to be used when creating or composing new icons, so you don't have to recreate the, well, common elements for each icon. Because of that, whenever I needed one of the icons from this, I just copied the one I needed into a new image and used that.

Read the readme files in the directory you want to use images from. For example it states in `_Common Elements\Objects\_MSCommonElements_Objects - Readme.html` (rough translation from my German version):

> These common elements are supposed to be used during development and design of new custom icons.

Comment: Not quite what it says, but close: Each .png file includes a transparent layer to allow for easy cutting and pasting into new images, and is made up of multiple sizes for each element. 

Thanks - makes sense now that you've said it out-loud :)

Comment: Actually, my translated quote is from the next paragraph (Usage Restrictions) after the one you quoted, at least in the German version :)